# When i click on ok on javascript alert dialog the page refreshed and alll the data inputed in the textbox will be blank

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<?php

  include "dbconfig.php";
  session_start();
  
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Log in</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style type="text/css">

  .error
  {
   color: red;
   

  }
  .form-control
  {
   color: black;
  }
  .btn

  {
   color: white;
  }

  .panel
  {
   width: 340px; 
   margin-left: 350px;
   margin-top:50px;
  }
  .form-control
  {
   width: 300px;
  }
   .right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
   .right-addon .glyphicon { right: 10px;} 
 </style>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <center><strong><h2>Log in</h2></strong></center>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <form method="post" role="form" id="login"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loginusername" placeholder="Username">
        
      </div>

       
      <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
       
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="loginpassword" placeholder="Password">
         

      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <h5><a href="#">forgot password ?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">issues while signing in ?</a></h5>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log in" name="lgn">
      </div>

      </form> 


     </div>


     <div class="panel-footer">
      <center>Don't have an account?<a href="sign_up.php">register</a></center>
     </div>


    </div>
   </div>



      <!-- Jquery Plugin CDN -->


     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
           integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
           crossorigin="anonymous">
          
       </script>


         <!-- Jquery Validation Plugin CDn -->

       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js">
        
       </script>

       
       <!-- Linking Page to index.js for form validation -->

       <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
        
       </script>


</body>
</html>


<?php 
 

  

  

 if (isset($_POST["lgn"])) 
 {
  

        $result=mysqli_query($db,"select * from signup where semail='$loginusername' and screatepass='$loginpassword'"); 


        if ($loginusername=="admin@gmail.com" && $loginpassword=="039218") {

         $_SESSION["session_admin"]=$loginusername;
         
         header("location:admin.php");

         
        }
        elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        
         header("location:Home.php");
            
        }   
        else
        {
         
         echo "<script>alert('Invalid username or password')</script>";

        }


 }



?>
```

When I click on ok on javascript alert dialog the page refreshed and all the data entered in the textbox will be blank. How to overcome this problem? I don't want this, I want that the page should not be refreshed after click on OK on javascript alert. I also added image with this question.

[image]

Comment: Please avoir doing such verification for login in your code

Answer (score 0):

You are not using AJAX to query the database, instead it needs to reload the page to run the PHP code on the server. This causes the inputs to be cleared. You should use an AJAX call to handle the database queries and input validation to fix this correctly, but as a workaround you can check in PHP if the post values for the fields are set and set them in the HTML, something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="loginusername" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['loginusername'])) echo $_POST['loginusername']; ?>">
<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="loginpassword" placeholder="Password" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['loginpassword'])) echo $_POST['loginpassword']; ?>">
```